# fb-js-sdk: why is getLoginStatus not called when using www for website

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

my FB.getLoginStatus handler does *not* fire if I use www for my website.

I load the fb-js-sdk into my website as normal:

```
var e   = document.createElement('script') ;                                    
e.type  = 'text/javascript'                ;                                     
e.src   = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
e.async = true;                                                                    
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
```

when my *fbAsyncInit* is called, I do:

```
FB.init( ... )
FB.getLoginStatus( my_handler )
```